# Save the best performing model (but not regarding validation acc) in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, keras, pytorch

Is there a way to replicate behavior of Keras earlyStopping method in PyTorch?
For example, if I want best model in regards of f1 score rather than acquired validation accuracy, is there an equivalent to Keras
`earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='f1_score', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')`?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box, you can either implement it yourself or use an external python package to handle it. If it's the former you want, then we might be able to help out.

Answer (score -1):

Pytorch has no callback functions like Keras does, so you'd have to take care of this manually.

Here's a rough pseudo-code outline:

```py
NUM_EPOCHS = 100
train_data, val_data = ...
model = ...
loss_fn = ...
optimizer = ...

# for early stopping
curr_best_f1 = 0.0
patience = 10

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    
    # training step
    model.train()
    train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer, train_data)

    # validation step
    model.eval()
    val_preds, val_labels = val_step(model, loss_fn, val_data)
    
    # check early stopping criterion
    f1_score = F1_Score(val_preds, val_labels)
    if f1_score >= curr_best_f1:
        curr_best_f1 = f1_score
        patience = 10
    else:
        patience -= 1
    
    if patience == 0:
        break
```

Change `F1_Score` to whatever metric you like to use and the `>=` accordingly if you like to have `min` instead of `max`. You may also want to put the early stopping checking in a separate function or small class.